# java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after connection closed

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have build an application, maintained with session.
It uses JDBC & mysql.

When the application is deployed on server (Apache Tomcat 6). I can log in and log out of the session. Works totally fine.

Now I keep the server running for next 24 hrs. And now on the next day I try to log in into the system after entering the credentials, on clicking the Login button I get the error on web page as below:
(what is the cause for this?)

**Http status 500**

**exception**

**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 11**

```
9:     Connection con =ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
10:     System.out.println("con "+con);
11:     con.setAutoCommit(false);
12:     Statement st = con.createStatement();
13:     ResultSet rs;
14:     rs = st.executeQuery("select * from ejduge_login where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd +"'");


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:524)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:417)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)


root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:850)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:779)
    org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:97)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)


root cause 

java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.checkClosed(Connection.java:2726)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.setAutoCommit(Connection.java:498)
    org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:65)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ConnectionProvider` is refusing connection, so `con` contains no connection, hence the error! :)

Comment: do you have any connection pool configured? What hidden in `ConnectionProvider.getConnection()` ?

Answer (score 5):

Well I found, the default time for closing connection if it has been inactive too long is 28800 seconds(8 hrs) for MYSQL **(& not 34,247,052 milliseconds)**.

```
show global variables;
```

In MYSQL, I reset that value to 172800 seconds(48 hrs as per my requirement) using

```
set global wait_timeout=172800;
```

and it worked fine.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The defaults can be found in oracles documentation for your specific version of mysql. Here is the defaults for 5.7: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Answer (score 2):

mysql will implicitly close the connection if it has been inactive too long time ( **34,247,052 milliseconds** by default ).

This would have caused the `No operations allowed after connection closed` error. so you could increase the inactive state timeout or handle it through efficient connection pooling

Answer (score -1):

it may just worked fine now, it will error after 172800 seconds,you should add check state  value and set the value less then 172800 .

just like c3p0  idleConnectionTestPeriod and maxIdleTime.